# Purpose of copper coils encountered in TV

Tags: identification, crt

I was recently working on an old TV similar to the one in this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvDf1Zi8cQg).  I began to open it and encountered a part on the TV which I have never came across, I believe it functions similarly to a cavity magnetron.

[image: image of inside of TV showing the wires]

Do anybody happen to know what part this is called (the enameled copper wires on the end of the tube)?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't vote your question down. But this area is for design questions. I'll answer your question, though.

Comment: @jonk  this is a perfectly n topic question

Comment: You really should not be opening CRT TVs or monitors if you do not know how they work - they are hazardous both in the potential of lethal voltage remaining on the tube (it is effectively a capacitor), and also can implode if mishandled, releasing hazardous dust from the screen phosphors.

Comment: @Scott: Then that's even better. I stand corrected. And this puts the question the OP asked even more strongly about why it may have been down-voted.

Comment: OP didn't take any initiative to find the answer in the internet? This is a question about the technology existed at least since last 70years..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the horizontal and vertical deflection coils. Check out the following link:

http://www.petervis.com/electronics%20guides/Sony%20KV-36FS76U/Deflection%20Coil.html

Comment: No problem. The web link was something google popped up for me and gave a quick, but I thought also useful, overview for you. I could have searched longer, I suppose. But that one looked okay to start.